# Download and autorun software trials via Flash?

Tags: flash

as a software developer, I offer free trial versions of my software for download. I can see from my stats that many that download the trials don't run them. My main target user is PC novices, so I think many of them doesn't realize they have to run the downloaded installer.

Question:

Would it be possible to write a small download client in Flash, that starts when the user clicks a download button, automatically downloads my .exe file and runs it when downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, and will be a very dangerous security flaw. You should make instructions clearer, somewhere around the download button, for your users to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Flash allows any way to get such access; Adobe Air will allow you to run Flash based applications on the desktop but I do not believe it runs in the browser.  However, I do know that Java applets can allow you to do such. The user will need the Java plug-in installed. By signing your applet, you can get access if the user allows it (it will ask them Yes or No). [Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) is a good tutorial on how. Hope that helps!